# Fastest and Safest Way to Emulate Auto-Increment using MAX in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

Assume that we have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
sid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
groupName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
userIdInGroup int,
PRIMARY KEY (sid));
```

We want to assign each new user in the same group an auto-increment userId based on the last userId of the group, i.e. we want to emulate an auto-increment userId within each group.

Since we are inserting the new userId considering the MAX(userIdInGroup) we need to wrap select and insert in a transaction. Something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION
SET @a = (SELECT MAX(userIdInGroup) FROM Persons WHERE groupName= 'Foo') +1;
INSERT THE NEW ROW USING userIdInGroup = @a
COMMIT
```

1. Is just selecting MAX in a transaction safe or do we need to lock something by SELECT FOR UPDATE?
2. Is there anyway to bypass transaction and still be consistent?

Comment: I just think this is a bad idea. Just store an auto-incrementing id, and calculate position in group as and when needed..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a MySql person, but I do have enough experience with other databases to know that this is a really bad idea. This `UserIdInGroup` can easily be calculated using `row_number`:

```
SELECT sid, 
       groupName, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY groupName ORDER BY sid) AS userIdInGroup
FROM Persons
```

And besides the fact that rolling your own auto-increment usually ends up giving wrong numbers (especially in a multi-threaded environment), what you can calculate easily (both in the code and in the performance aspect) should not be stored anyway.

Comment: You can only do this in MySQL 8+, but there are other techniques for older versions . The principle remains the same

Comment: @Strawberry as I said, I'm not a MySql guy. Feel free to edit my answer with a solution to lower versions, or add another answer with that solution.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know this type of autoincrement is a bad idea but it is a force for our business to give sequential ids within each group with the fastest possible method.