# how to set the datetime to zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to set the datetime value to zeros for the date and the time in a query 
I am getting

> the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

```
select case when DATECOMPLETED is null then '0000-00-00 00:00:00' else DATECOMPLETED end from FDWELCOMECALL
```

Comment: Why not go with NULL instead of zero?

Comment: this is what is required from the user

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), your value is not a valid value:

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Choose a valid value for the default.  Or learn to live with `NULL` values.

I should also point out that a month of "0" and a day of "0" are not valid dates.

Note:  `COALESCE()` would simplify the logic:

```
select coalesce(DATECOMPLETED, '1000-01-01 00:00:00') from FDWELCOMECALL
```

Comment: is `coalesce(DATECOMPLETED is null` valid ??

Comment: @gordon What does is null do?

Comment: @Susang . . . That was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `0000` is not a valid year and `00` is not a valid month.
The best you can do is to leave it as `null`.
If that's not an option, use the minimum / maximum value for datetime:
`1000-01-01 00:00:00` / `9999-12-31 23:59:59`

As strawberry pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401615/how-to-set-the-datetime-to-zero/54401684?noredirect=1#comment95614568_54401684), the `Date` data type does support `0000-00-00` (though [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) states it's the value for invalid date/datetime values).

Comment: Well, 00 is a valid day

Comment: @Strawberry in what date system is 00 a valid day?

Comment: In MySQL. The only one we're talking about

Comment: @Strawberry really? What date is `2019-01-00`?

Comment: It's a date with a defined month but an undefined day http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0fa57/1 - in the attached example, the error is in java, not sql.

Comment: It seems day=00 means "last day in previous month", at least that's how that fiddle displays data if you remove the one with year=0000.

Comment: Perhaps this is a clearer example. The date is valid in the sense that MySQL accepts it as valid. https://rextester.com/IEVW18148

Comment: Well, as I said not so long ago, [I'm not a MySql guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54341567/3094533)... I stand corrected.

Comment: Well actually, the default behaviour may have changed in 5.7 and 8.0

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this answer to another question, the datetime type doesn't go that low. You most likely need to use NULL.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13179063/2793683

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to alter the table column with default value

```
ALTER TABLE FDWELCOMECALL ALTER DATECOMPLETED SET DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00';
```